# Trying to migrate online store,completely lost and being taken advantage of

Tags: migration, shopify, hosting, store

We have an online store that used to be managed by a third party (lets call them BS Company) that did the hosting, webdesign and everything... Now we've decided to move to Shopify because this company has screwed us over in every step along the way.

We already have the store ready on Shopify. Our current website is hosted on DigitalOcean, for which BsCompany has all the access.

They are being impossible, saying that they can't transfer out of DigitalOcean because they have several client's sites with the same hosting. This sounds like royal BS. We just want to move everything to shopify.

I'm going to be on the phone with them shortly, I just want to be informed. What should I ask them to do specifically? What I'm I trying to get them to do?

I'm totally lost here guys, please help.

Comment: StackOverflow is intended for programming questions.

Comment: The important thing is that you have control of your own domain. You just switch it https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains . As pointed out in the answer, migrating all your orders, customers, catalogues etc is another matter entirely but if you have control of your own domain you can switch away from a bad provider easily.

Answer (score 2):

This goes outside of the scope of StackOveflow purpose which is to help developers with their code issues.

---

That said you are providing too little information here.

If you want to transfer your store to Shopify and the theme is already done then you need probably only the content from the old store.

Since you didn't mentioned what is the previous platform (WordPress/Drupal/Magento/etc...) it will be hard to provide a recommendation for an App that will import the content from the other platform to Shopify.

So pretty much you need to know what platform the current store is using. For example if you are using WordPress with WooCommerce you will need the following App in Shopify -> https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/migrating-to-shopify/import-store-app/woocommerce-migration and you will need to export the content from the WordPress.

Please have in mind that this will focus mainly on the products, if you like to import the pages and custom post types ( we are still are talking about WordPress here ) you will need some other App or custom logic.

So long story short is not an easy job if there is no App for it.

---

If you want to keep the SEO for your previous site please have in mind that the Shopify have a predefined URL structure that you can't overwrite.

This means that pages that were using a specific url structure will be different now and you will need to create redirect rules in Shopify manually for each page, which will be a tedious process if you have too much content.

---

So pretty much you need to know:

- What platform the site was written at
- Export of the database ( and what database was used MySQL/MongoDB/etc... )
- The site files ( they need to provide them to you )

With this information you will be able to create a local copy of the site for reference.